# How do I configure active record to use a certain column to get the id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm dealing with legacy database, and so configuration will have to trump convention..

How do I tell active record to use `signature` to get info about the `signatures` table?

This is my Event Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | signature | timestamp
  #----------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'event'
  has_many :sensors, :foreign_key => :sid
  has_many :signatures, :foreign_key => :sig_id
end
```

This is my Signature Model:

```
class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sig_id | sig_name | sig_class_id | sig_priority | sig_rev | sig_sid | sig_gid

  attr_accessible :sig_id, :sig_name, :sig_class_id, :sig_priority, :sig_rev, :sig_sid, :sig_gid
  self.table_name = 'signature'
  self.primary_key = :sig_id
  belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => :sig_id
  belongs_to :sig_class
  has_many :references, :through => :sig_references
  has_many :sig_references, :foreign_key => :sig_id
end
```

For example. When looking at one event the `sid` is 4 and the `signature` is 493.

```
[196] pry(main)> last_event
=> #<Event sid: 4, cid: 49, signature: 493, timestamp: "2014-06-25 20:22:57">
```

If I look at the sensors it uses the correct id, the `sid`.

```
[197] pry(main)> last_event.sensors
=> [#<Sensor sid: 4, hostname: "VS-101-Z1:dna2:dna3", interface: "dna2:dna3", filter: nil, detail: 1, encoding: 0, last_cid: 51>]
```

When I look at the signatures, its uses the same id `sid`, not `signature`

```
[198] pry(main)> last_event.signatures
=> [#<Signature sig_id: 4, sig_name: "FILE-JAVA Oracle Java Rhino script engine remote co...", sig_class_id: 3, sig_priority: 1, sig_rev: 6, sig_sid: 23008, sig_gid: 1>]
```

UPDATE:

I got it working, I changed my Event model to this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | signature | timestamp
  #----------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'event'

  has_many :sensors,
           :foreign_key => :sid

  has_many :signatures,
           :foreign_key => :sig_id,
           :primary_key => :signature
end
```

Basically just added `:primary_key => :signature` to the `has_many`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Signature model, including these lines of code:

```
self.primary_key = :sig_id
belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => :sig_id
```

The first says that the key of the table `signature` is the field `:sig_id`.

The second line says that this signature record belongs to an event record whose key is stored at the field `:sig_id` of the current signature record.

I guess one of these fields is wrong because it can't be always the same value the key of Event and the key of Signature.

Edit: After your update, I've seen that your event model has a field called `signature` with the value of the `signature` key. Then I can say that one record of event, allow only one signature (the one whose key is stored at field `signature`). At the same time, one record of signature can be related to many record of event.

Then, your associations must be: An Event `belongs_to :signature`, and A Signature `has_many :events`.

I guess you are using [composite-primary-key](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) gem. Them your models may look this way:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  ...
  belongs_to :signatures, :foreign_key => :signature
end

class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :events, :foreing_key => :signature, :primary_key => :sig_id
  ...
end
```

Comment: That make total since. I changed this line `belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => :signature` but it did not work. Maybe there is something else I'm missing.

Comment: I think at Event model this line `self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid` is not correct, but I'm not sure. The standard use is `self.primary_key = :sid` singular and one field.

Comment: Ops, `belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => :the_key`. `the_key` must be a field of signature table that stores the key of events.

Comment: The Event model has two primary keys in this case, that's why I have `self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid`. Love legacy database schemas...

Comment: At this time I must go out. Tomorrow I'll see the status.